# Make an hover stay hovered until next link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

first of all just want to say that i'm **not** a programer but i'm trying to replicate a code and since my javascript is not the best i'm failing at it.

The "animation" in css/java/wtv i'm trying to replicate is from the 3 first boxes links on this site:
http://artcom.de

As you can see when you hover the box/link it stays hovered until the the mouse goes over another link.

I found some solutions with javascript that envolve animating and use a `.stop().animate(` function but that makes impossible to code css on top of it, one of the things is put a different background image when hovered different a link (that i can make i just can't put the box hovered until the next link).

If you find my question to much of a request feel free to not answer. It's my first post and since coding is a thing that i'm starting i feel kinda nervous of asking this questions.

Thanks in advance for any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is similar to that of SW4, but offers a slightly different variation. Basically, when you hover over an item, you want to add a style class to it, while removing that class from all of the other (possibly previously hovered) items.

**FIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/44c9x5eb/2/**

In my fiddle, I use a `div` item called `#body` instead of styling the actual body element.

**HTML**

```
<div id='body'></div>

<div class="item" data-bg="http://www.evokia.com/images/large-background.jpg">1</div>
<div class="item" data-bg="http://p1.pichost.me/i/10/1333648.jpg">2</div>
<div class="item" data-bg="http://www.desktopaper.com/wp-content/uploads/wonderful-fish-wallpaper-large-background.jpg">3</div>
<div class="item" data-bg="http://p1.pichost.me/640/17/1397737.jpg">4</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#body{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:#eee;
    z-index:0;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;  
    transition: all 350ms ease-in;     
}
.item{
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
    margin:0 8px;
    background:#f00;
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
}
.item.selected{
    background:#0f0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.item').mouseover(function(){

    //If this item is already selected, forget about it.
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) return;

    //Find the currently selected item, and remove the style class
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');

    //Add the style class to this item
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    //set the body to a different image
    $('#body').css( 'background-image', 'url(' + $(this).data('bg') + ')' );
});
```

Comment: Thank you for such a good answer. You could have just make the buttons but even include the changing of images in the bg. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could use the below to simply apply a 'hover' class on mouseover of a valid element, after stripping it from similarly qualifying ones. The animation can be handled in CSS using a `transition`

```js
$('div').on('mouseover', function() {
  $('div').removeClass('hover');
  $(this).addClass('hover');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
div {
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>link</div>
<div>link</div>
<div>link</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

basically you need to do two things.

- Create an active class for the selected button in css that defines
  the background color
- Bind to the Hover event add the class to the
  hovered over button and remove the class from the other buttons.

This will look something like this:

```js
$('button').hover(
  //this function is called on hoverin
  function() {
    //remove the css class from all buttons
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    //add the class on the hovered over button
    $(this).addClass('active');
  },
  //this function is called on hoverin not needed in this case
  function() {}
);
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: white;
}
button {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>button1</button>
<button>button1</button>
<button>button1</button>
```

Keep in mind that in today's landscape a lot of mobile devices are being used to visit your site. Therefore you should not build actual functionality relying on hover events. i.e: A menu that opens up when you hover over it.

Comment: Thank you i didn't think of that but the website i'm building will only be ready for late january so i learn a few more things till then... :)